# What does the ALSO keyword mean in MLISP?

Tags: lisp

I've been looking over the [source code](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/areas/classics/parry/) for the early AI project [Parry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PARRY) recently. It's tricky because the bulk of the code is written in [MLISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MLisp), for which no working implementation still exists (that I know of). Instead, I've been using the language specification ([MLISP Users' Manual](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/stanford/Smith-MLISP-AIM-84.pdf) and the earlier [MLISP Technical Report](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/68/92/CS-TR-68-92.pdf)).

One curiosity that I haven't been able to explain is the `IF-THEN-ELSE-ALSO` construct, e.g.:

```
IF !LAMBDANAME(B) THEN ERROR("NONLAMBDA INTO REACT2",B) ALSO RETURN NIL;
```

The documentation I have been able to find does not mention an `ALSO` clause for the `IF` statement, and I'm scratching my head a bit to understand what it's for.

One plausible suggestion I've seen is that it's used the way the `finally` clause is used for exception handling in Java, i.e. to run cleanup code no matter how the `IF` is terminated.  On the other hand, that doesn't explain statements that appear never to raise exceptions, like:

```
IF REACTTO='QUIT THEN REACTTO:=NIL ALSO TRACE_MEM:='NOSPECIALANAPH;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Total guess, but maybe it's just a piece of syntactic sugar for running the second statement after the first, in this case, an IF...ELSE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
IF e1 THEN a ALSO b ALSO c ELSE d ALSO e ALSO f
```

Is just

```
(COND (e1 a b c) (T d e f))
```

See [MLISP](http://i.stanford.edu/TR/CS-TR-70-179.html) from David Canfield Smith, 1970.

Comment: So `a also b also c` is essentially sugar for `(progn () a b c)`?

Comment: I'm MLISP-ignorant - does `progn` need that empty form?  In CL I would've just said `(progn a b c)`.

Comment: @khedron: no, that's just me being sloppy and confusing `progn` with `prog`.

Comment: @TimPierce: No. ALSO is a part of the IF THEN ALSO ELSE ALSO syntax. It does not exist alone.

Comment: @TimPierce: it's described in the October 1970 version of the User's Manual.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant in the context of an `IF` statement. Thanks for clarifying and also for the pointer to the 1970 manual.